# File is writing into wrong path using PHP

Tags: php, file

I am uploading file into folder using PHP but my issue is its at a time writing file into 2 different path. My code is below.

```
if(array_key_exists('pimage',$_FILES)){
                $tempFile = $_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name'];
                $fileName = $_FILES['pimage']['name'];
                $fileName = str_replace(" ", "-", $_FILES['pimage']['name']);
                $fig = rand(1, 999999);
                $saveFile = $fig . '_' . $fileName;
                $uploadOk = 1;
                if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name']) ==  IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
                    $ext=pathinfo($saveFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $saveFile=$ext.'.png';
                    $png = imagepng(imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name']), $saveFile);
                }
                if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name']) ==  IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
                    $ext=pathinfo($saveFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $saveFile=$ext.'.png';
                    $png = imagepng(imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name']), $saveFile);
                }
                if (strpos($fileName,'php') !== false) {
                    # code...
                }else{
                    $targetPath = PT_USERS_IMAGES_UPLOAD;
                    $targetFile = $targetPath . $saveFile;
                    if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
                        $data=array("msg"=>'profile image already exists');
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if ($_FILES["pimage"]["size"] > 2000000 || $_FILES["pimage"]["size"] == 0) {
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                        $data=array("msg" => "profile image should not greater than 2 MB.");
                    }
                    //echo $uploadOk;exit;
                    if ($uploadOk==0) {
                        $flag=0;
                        $data[]=array("msg" => $data['msg']);
                    }else{
                        $moved =move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
                        if ($moved) {
                            $filename = $saveFile;
                            $data = array('ai_image' => $filename);
                            $this->db->where('accounts_id', $dataArr['user_id']);
                            $this->db->update('pt_operator_accounts', $data);
                        }else{
                            $flag=0;
                            $data[]=array("msg" => "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["pimage"]["error"]);
                        }
                       // print_r($data);exit;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here I need to write file into `PT_USERS_IMAGES_UPLOAD` path but before uploading into this path also the file is uploading into project's root path. Here I need to upload only in `PT_USERS_IMAGES_UPLOAD` path not in project's root path.

Comment: So u mean to say file is uploading on both root and T_USERS_IMAGES_UPLOAD Path?

Comment: @Jaymin: Yes its uploading both field.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], so that every information for reproducing the issue is in your question. Also, are you perhaps assuming that PHP is executed by a webserver? You should state that as well, unless of course your issue can reproduced without a webserver as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely because of these lines:

```
imagepng(imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['pimage']['tmp_name']), $saveFile);
```

If you look at the documentation regarding this [imagepng()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), it will either output an image to the browser (with a proper header) or save the file to disk when you fill out the second parameter, in your case you have used the `to` parameter (`$saveFile`). So, once you save it there, you then save it again using the `move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);` which is the one saving it to the proper location.

If you are trying to convert something to PNG, then just do the `imagepng()` line and remove the `move_uploaded_file()` line. Change `$saveFile` to `T_USERS_IMAGES_UPLOAD` and then you should only get one saved file. Either way, remove one of those methods for saving the file to disk.